# Capture SessionID with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I create a link containing my sessionID in javascript?

My javascript code is (which I would like to bring the sessionID):

```
location.href="transpage.asp"
```

And this is the asp code which brings sessionID:

```
<% mLink = "rec_edit.asp?ObjectID=" & mObjectID & "&sessionid=" & request("SessionID") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well quick and dirty it would be

```
 location.href="transpage.asp<%= "?ObjectID=" & mObjectID & "&sessionid=" &
 request("SessionID") %>";
```

since the asp code is rendered server side and the js code is executed client side it would work, but why would you pass the session id as get parameter when you're obvisouly staying on the same site? sorry for beeing so curios

Comment: Thanks ,  forget about dirty  first , i need to complete my task asap  , it would be very helpful~

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function GetSessionValue()
       {
         <% if( HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"]!=null) { %>
var SessionId = <%= HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"].ToString() %>; 
                alert('+ SessionId +');
                return SessionId ;
         }  %>

 }
```